# Some images are not showing in react-native-fastimage

Tags: ios, react-native, amazon-s3

I'm making an iOS app using react-native.

But I got some problem in the [react-native-fastimage](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) library.

Firstly, the code below is showing properly:

```
<FastImage
   style={s.image}
   source={{
      uri: 'https://unsplash.it/400/400?image=1',
      priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
   }}
   resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.stretch}
/>
```

But, this is not showing:

```
<FastImage
   style={s.image}
   source={{
      uri: 'https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/zzim-app-images/intro/180529_1.png',
      headers:{ Authorization: 'someAuthToken' },
      priority: FastImage.priority.high,
   }}
   resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.stretch}
/>
```

Why can't I see any image?
Can't I load image from s3?

Below were that I tested.

1. I downloaded "https://unsplash.it/400/400?image=1" and uploaded to s3 but it's not showing too.
2. I tried to use `<Image>` component, it works. The problem is with FastImage and S3 Image.
3. I added 'Content-Type' in headers but it's still not showing..
4. I tried to apply other images that aren't s3 images (big size, png, jpeg, etc..).
   They are displaying properly.
5. I tried to reinstall node_module, init project and remove cache. But images from s3 were still not showing.

I don't know what's the problem. Please help me..

PS) package.json

```
{
  "name": "ZzimIos",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.3.1",
    "native-base": "^2.7.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-blur": "^3.2.2",
    "react-native-carousel-view": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.4",
    "react-native-masonry": "^0.5.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.0.2397",
    "react-native-scalable-image": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.0.6",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "recompose": "^0.26.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^3.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.11.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.2.1",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-native-debugger-open": "^0.3.17",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: @shim Thank u for editing :)

Answer (score 1):

I've the same issue, 
Can u pls remove the headers parameter from the Fastimage request

Then your code will be look like :

```
<FastImage
   style={s.image}
   source={{
      uri: 'https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/zzim-app-images/intro/180529_1.png',
      priority: FastImage.priority.high,
   }}
   resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.stretch}
/>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Having the same issue, but your solution is not working unfortunately